# select taking a lot of time on table with many rows

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have this select:

```
select 'like' prefix
     , l.post
     , l.data as data
     , l.user
     , concat(k.user, ' liked you') as logs 
  from likes l 

inner join posts p on l.post = p.id 
inner join cadastro k on l.user = k.id 
where p.user = 1 and l.user <> p.user

order by data desc
limit 10
```

it took 2.3993 seconds.

[image]
any ideas to improve?

```
`likes` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `post` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_post` (`user`,`post`),
  KEY `post_user` (post, user),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES cadastro (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`post`) REFERENCES posts (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

`posts` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`cadastro` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

any ideas to speed this up? I also tried to add index on likes data, but no diference noticed.

Comment: I feel like we did this already?!?

Comment: @Strawberry yes! but the query was on a union all, and I notice that this like part is the one with the problem, so I decided to explain better in this post. I also tried your tip, to change the `<>` part but the result was the same.

Comment: But we got as far as `where p.user = 1 and l.user <> 1`. What happened to that?

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't notice any speed improviment ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  'like' prefix ,
        l.post ,
        l.data as data ,
        l.user ,
        ( SELECT concat(user, ' liked you')
              FROM cadastro  WHERE id = l.user ) AS logs
    from  likes l
    inner join  posts p  ON l.post = p.id
    where  p.user = 1
      and  l.user <> p.user
    order by  data desc
    limit  10
```

Indexes:

```
p: (user, data, id)  -- 'covering'; helps WHERE; may help ORDER BY
l: (post)
cadastro: I assume you have PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

Further improvement:  Change the `likes` indexes from

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `user_post` (`user`,`post`),
KEY `post_user` (post, user),
```

to

```
PRIMARY KEY(post, user),
INDEX(user, post)
```

and get rid of `id`.

Caveat: If no one 'liked you', the resultset may be different with this query.  If this is an issue, I will reformulate it to use a 'derived' table.

By moving the cadastro lookup into a subquery, I think that action is occurring less often than if cadastro were in a `JOIN`.  This is not a universal optimization -- note that the `WHERE` clause is complex since it involves more than one table.  I'm unclear on whether the index on `p` will make it all the way through `data`, and help at all with `LIMIT`.  For further investigation, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: Thank you very much!! it is strange but using subquery in cadastro helped to speed it up to 4x. can you explain why it is better than inner join?

Comment: @RickJoe - I made a stab at answering you via an added paragraph in my Answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is your query:

```
select 'like' as prefix, l.post, l.data as data, l.user,
        concat(k.user, ' liked you') as logs
from likes l join
     posts p
     on l.post = p.id oin
     cadastro k
     on l.user = k.id 
where p.user = 1 and l.user <> p.user
order by data desc
limit 10;
```

For this query, you want indexes on `post(user, id)`, `likes(post, user, data)`, and `cadastro(id, user)`.

You cannot do much to remove the overhead for the `order by`, but this should speed up the join and filtering parts of the query.

Comment: thanks, it dropped to 1.5186 seconds. not that good, but a little faster tho.